# What regular expression can I use to split a string into a a-zA-Z pairs?

Tags: regex

Can somebody tell me how a regular expression should look like which searches in

```
V. Guimaraes - FC-Porto
```

and gives out:

1. `V. Guimaraes`
2. `FC-Porto`

The Source also could be:

1. `V. Guimaraes - FC-Porto 2:2`
2. `V. Guimaraes - FC-Porto Foo`

So, I don't want my pair to contain the score.

Comment: Need more information about the full structure of the text you are parsing (like perhaps multiple lines of example text), also you could consider just playing around with at tool like regexr - http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - which will show you what matches fairly easily as you type

Comment: Please, edit the question and add more details about the text. For example, is this possible: "Blah V. Guimaraes - FC-Porto blah"? And this: "V. Guimaraes - FC-Porto. blah"?

Comment: How do you know "Foo" isn't part of the name on the right-hand side of the hyphen? And what if "V. Guimaraes" was on the right-hand side instead? Sounds like you'd need a list of possible names to look this up against. Also, soccer and programming don't mix. :)

Comment: @Roberto Looks like Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

You could just split the string at " - " with your programing language's basic string functions. This way you don't even need any regular expressions.

Comment: There is more Text after it, sorry missed to post it.

Answer (score 0):

how about `(.*) - (.*)`?

Comment: the problem is, that after it there are additional infos e.g.:

Comment: "V. Guimaraes - FC-Porto 2:2" OR "V. Guimaraes - FC-Porto Foo"

Comment: @mullek: You should edit this information into your question. It is very important information when constructing a regular expression (or any other approach for parsing this data). In fact, it would be very useful to see a couple of full lines that you want to extract information from, along with the information you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

```
([\S\W]*)[\s]{1}-[\s]{1}([\S\W]*)
```

And you can fetch answer from group 1 and group 2 `$1:$2`

Answer (score 0):

Search for: `"(V.\s+Guimaraes)\s*-\s*(FC-Porto\b).*?"\s+"\1\s*-\s*\2.*?"`

Replace with: `"$1"\r"$2"`

So, if your are using PHP, it will be:

```
  $result = preg_replace('/"(V.\s+Guimaraes)\s*-\s*(FC-Porto\b).*?"\s+"\1\s*-\s*\2.*?"/', '"$1"\r"$2"', $sourcestring);
```

The key is `$1` `$2` which hold the first and the second result.
`\r` means return characters (enter), you can replace it with anything you wish, e.g. a space.

Next time, please mention regex library or application you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split` function of your preferred language to do this. eg Python

```
>>> s="V. Guimaraes - FC-Porto 2:2"
>>> s.split("-",1)
['V. Guimaraes ', ' FC-Porto 2:2']
```